# Smooch integration for web agents and multiple organisations

Tags: smooch

I have been asked to integrate [smooch](https://smooch.io/) into our CMS.

We have multiple agents from multiple companies that can login on our web CMS, and are uniquely identified by their organisation + agent e-mail. These are the agents, and they will connect through our web interface (CMS).

However, setting up the chat box via `Smooch.init(...)` lets the user logged into the CMS initiate a conversation, which is not what I want (I enabled a slack integration just for testing).

My question is what is the proper way to distinguish a user from an agent in a web context?

Specifically, how do I configure the web box *as an agent box for a specific organisation* ?

I am looking for something like :

```
Smooch.init({...,
             'organisation' : 'myClientCompany',
             'role' : 'appMaker'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with their support, it appears that this is not something they support. One workaround would be to create multiple accounts.